# When you play poker in Red Dead Redemption, is the "look around" option actually useful?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

In Red Dead Redemption, during the poker game, you can look around at other people's faces. I assume there's a use of this option, but I wasn't able to get any hint when it may be. Does it actually have a purpose, or is it just for game immersion ?

Answer (score 3):

Well technically it has a purpose and also adds to game immersion ;)

In all seriousness the NPC players give off tells as well as change their tones/mannerisms slightly depending on past hands and their current hands. The look around option gives you a chance to watch for those tells and play accordingly. It can also give you a better idea of when to cheat, since most of the time the other players will catch you (if you're as bad at it as I am).

Comment: do you have any examples of such behaviors ?

Comment: I don't have specific gameplay footage (I'm sure youtube has some) but I've seen NPCs act differently as [this thread](http://reddeadfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&p=1430) mentions.

Answer (score 0):

If you look around after several hands you can tell who is bluffing and who has a good hand. You can also use it to determine if you can get away with cheating.

Comment: ? If i could downvote i would. Op is asking *how* to do this

Comment: If you want I can delete my response. I was just agreeing with the first answer and since I cant up vote or put in a comment I just added it as an answer.